# Display "download now" on products that have 0 price prestashop 1.7

Tags: button, prestashop, checkout, prestashop-1.7, price

ps 1.7

I have a virtual store , and i want to change "add to cart" button to "download now" when price is zero . my mean , For free products, change the "Add to Cart" button to the "Download"

i used this in product.tpl:

```
        {if $product->price <= 0}
        {l s='Download now'}
        {else}
        {l s='Add to cart' d='Shop.Theme.Actions'}
        {/if}
```

but not worked,
so how can i fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

it solved by this :

```
    <div class="add">
      <button
        class="btn btn-primary add-to-cart"
        data-button-action="add-to-cart"
        type="submit"
        {if !$product.add_to_cart_url}
          disabled
        {/if}
      >
        <i class="material-icons shopping-cart">&#xE547;</i>
        {if $product.price_amount <= 0}
          {l s='Download now'}
        {else}
          {l s='Add to cart' d='Shop.Theme.Actions'}
        {/if}
      </button>
    </div>
```

original thread :
https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/1034864-display-download-now-on-products-that-have-0-price/